# Differentiate between text and spans

Tags: javascript, html

I want to update the innerHTML of a div, but want to handle text differently if it already belongs to a span

```html
<div id="a">
Here is some text
<span>Here is some more span text</span>
More Text...
<span>contains TARGET</span>
Another Line with the TARGET
</div>
```

My goal is to replace all instances of `TARGET` with `<span class="target-class">TARGET</span>` if it isn't already in a span. My code currently loops through children and before doing the replacement checks if the tag = SPAN and the span contains the `target-class`.

```html
<div id="a">
Here is some text
<span>Here is some more span text</span>
More Text...
<span>contains TARGET</span>
Another Line with the <span class="target-class">TARGET</span>
</div>
```

When I call `.innerHTML` on `#a` it returns the full div HTML. When I loop through `#a`'s children it loops through the spans -- I'm hoping there's some way to loop through what I'll loosely call the `text fragments` so I can replace their `innerHTML`

Current Code:

Wrapping logic to loop through document elements

```
export async function updateLabels(includedItems: Set<string>, excludedItems: Set<string>, allItems: Set<string>) {
  visitChildren(
    document.body,
    [
      (element: HTMLElement) => replaceItemWithTag(element, allItems, `<span class="custom-label">$1</span>`),
    ],
  )
  // Ignore this - it loops through all elements w/ the "custom-label" class and adds another class "custom-label--include"/"custom-label--exclude" depending on which set it belongs to
  // setItemClassifications(includedItems, excludedItems)
}
```

dom walk code:

```
export function visitChildren(
    element: HTMLElement,
    visitors: ((element: Element) => [boolean, string[]])[],
) {

    for (let i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
        if (element.children[i].tagName === "SCRIPT") {
            // skip scripts
            continue;
        }
        if (element.children[i].tagName === "STYLE") {
            // skip style
            continue;
        }

        const childVisitors: ((element: Element) => [boolean, string[]])[] = [];
        const childVisitorReasons: [boolean, string[]][] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < visitors.length; j++) {
            const visitor = visitors[j];
            const [result, reasons] = visitor(element.children[i]);
            childVisitorReasons.push([result, reasons]);
            if (result) {
                childVisitors.push(visitor);
            }
        }


        if (childVisitors.length > 0) {
            visitChildren(element.children[i] as HTMLElement, childVisitors);
        }
    }

}
```

replacement code for this instance:

```
export function replaceItemWithTag(element: HTMLElement, targets: Set<string>, replaceWith: string): [boolean, string[]] {
    const targetArray = Array.from(targets);
    const reg = RegExp(`\\b(${targetArray.join("|")})\\b`, "ig");
    const reason: string[] = [
        `targets: ${targetArray.join(",")}`,
        `regex: ${reg}`,
    ];

    // skip element if it's already been replaced
    if (element.classList.contains("custom-label")) {
        reason.push("already replaced")
        return [false, reason]
    }

    let innerHTMLIncludesATarget = false;
    for (const target of targetArray) {
        if (element.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(target)) {
            innerHTMLIncludesATarget = true;
            break;
        }
    }


    if (!innerHTMLIncludesATarget) {
        reason.push("no target in innerHTML")
        if (debugPrint) { console.log({ element, innerHTML: element.innerHTML, innerText: element.innerText, filter: false, reason }) }
        return [false, reason];
    }
    reason.push("target in innerHTML")

    let innerTextIncludesATarget = false;
    for (const target of targetArray) {
        if (element.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(target)) {
            innerTextIncludesATarget = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (innerTextIncludesATarget) {
        reason.push("target is in innerText")

        // The issue is here -- I'm not checking the text, only the sub - spans
        if (element.children.length === 0) {
            reason.push("no children")
            element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(reg, replaceWith);
            reason.push("replaced")

            return [false, reason]; // don't visit children if we've already replaced the string
        }
        if (debugPrint) { console.log({ element, innerHTML: element.innerHTML, innerText: element.innerText, filter: true, reason }) }

        return [true, reason]
    }
    return [true, reason]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of the DOM (Document Object Model) each browser handles it differently. the `Target` text is stored as a node, which has no type (tags like div, etc)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Text nodes do have a type, specifically: [`Node.TEXT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

Comment: Can you post your current code as well? This way we can point out where you went wrong.

Comment: Spans will get added progressively - everything works with the initial load, but additional spans fail because they aren't identified w/in a childless element. A hacky work-around would be to remove all spans then re-add them (with the new ones)

Comment: I have the childless constraint to avoid nested spans, but I could relax this constraint

Comment: I think I would be worth it to get rid of that code all together and replace it. Modern browsers have capabilities to do it with a lot less en better understandable code as you can see in Unmitigated's answer.

Comment: I'm looking at Unmitigated's answer now (seeing how to apply it). FMI, how would you restructure things? `updateLabels` applies a generic masking functions to the dom walk (that's useful if you do a lot of dom walking), `visitChildren` performs the dom walking - I'm trying to re-implement this with Nodes now. `replaceItemWithTag` attempts to prune the tree instead of walking the full sub tree while replacing the spans. At their core I think each function is needed, no? Are there builtin document methods that handle these activities?

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaijens i meant to say that.

Comment: @Schalton I added an answer with a recursive function. I think that is what you mean with dom walking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the `childNodes` of the container to find all the text nodes, then use `replaceWith` to replace the node with a new set of nodes.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#a');
for (const node of el.childNodes) 
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    node.replaceWith(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
      node.textContent.replaceAll('TARGET', '<span class="target-class">$&</span>')
    ));
  }
```

```css
.target-class { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="a">
Here is some text
<span>Here is some more span text</span>
More Text...
<span>contains TARGET</span>
Another Line with the TARGET
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the key thing here was `document.createRange().createContextualFragment` -- it doesn't seem like TS can appreciate the inheritance structure in the DOM, that's why I pivoted from Nodes to Elements, this worked cleanly -- I added `(node as Element)` to coerce.

Answer (score 0):

With this I expanded @Unmitigated answer how the same can be applied with a recursive function to also apply the logic to child nodes.

So I wrapped the logic in a function and call that from within the function on childnodes (when elements).

```js
wrapTextWithTag(document.querySelector('#a').childNodes, 'TARGET', '<span class="target-class">$&</span>');

function wrapTextWithTag(nodelist, text, tag) {
  for (const node of nodelist) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      node.replaceWith(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
        node.textContent.replaceAll(text, tag)
      ));
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      wrapTextWithTag(node.childNodes, text, tag);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.target-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  Here is some text
  <span>Here is some more span text</span>
  More Text...
  <span>contains TARGET</span>
  Another Line with the TARGET
  <div>
    Here is some text
    <span>Here is some more span text</span>
    More Text...
    <span>contains TARGET</span>
    Another Line with the TARGET
    <div>
      Here is some text
      <span>Here is some more span text</span>
      More Text...
      <span>contains TARGET</span>
      Another Line with the TARGET
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```