# Skip TEXT_NODEs containing html/css/js

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first chrome extension - be kind

Symptoms:

1. Google home page loads without issue
2. Google Search Results populate, but ~.5 seconds later the page clears, the DOM content isn't lost but the body size drops to 0x0
3. This only happens on Google (I haven't reproduced it on any other site)
4. The console outputs, aside from debug logs in my extension, are identical between `google-with extension`, `google w/out extension`, and `duckduckgo-with extension

About the Extension:

- My extension isn't specific to the google home page, I'm using the `<all_urls>` tag.
- Uses sync storage to allow the user to maintain a list of keywords
- Highlights those keywords by wrapping them in a span.
- Context/Select menu for managing keywords

---

Alright, found the root cause. My code loops over the nodes in the dom, searches for a keywords and replaces instances with a spans as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762675/differentiate-between-text-and-spans?noredirect=1#comment135330889_76762675).

The issue is one of those keywords is `http`. Despite filtering by TEXT_NODEs the replacement is happening on a node with the following content:

```
"<style>table,div,span,p{display:none}</style><meta content="0;url=/search?q=search+labs&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=N1XCZP_eDeakptQP5uK0mAw" http-equiv="refresh"><div style="display:block">Please click <a href="/search?q=search+labs&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=N1XCZP_eDeakptQP5uK0mAw">here</a> if you are not redirected within a few seconds.</div>"
```

formatted

```html
<style>
  table,div,span,p{display:none}
</style>
<meta
  content="0;url=/search?q=search+labs&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=N1XCZP_eDeakptQP5uK0mAw"
  http-equiv="refresh"
>
<div
  style="display:block"
>
  Please click
  <a href="/search?q=search+labs&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=N1XCZP_eDeakptQP5uK0mAw">
    here
  </a>
  if you are not redirected within a few seconds.
</div>
```

converting to

```
"<style>table,div,span,p{display:none}</style><meta content="0;url=/search?q=search+labs&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=N1XCZP_eDeakptQP5uK0mAw" <span class="label">http</span>-equiv="refresh"><div style="display:block">Please click <a href="/search?q=search+labs&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=N1XCZP_eDeakptQP5uK0mAw">here</a> if you are not redirected within a few seconds.</div>"
```

formatted

```
<style>
  table,div,span,p{display:none}
</style>
<meta
  content="0;url=/search?q=search+labs&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=N1XCZP_eDeakptQP5uK0mAw"
  <span class="keyword">http</span>-equiv="refresh"
>

<div
  style="display:block"
>
  Please click
  <a href="/search?q=search+labs&amp;gbv=1&amp;sei=N1XCZP_eDeakptQP5uK0mAw">
    here
  </a>
  if you are not redirected within a few seconds.
</div>
```

`http-equiv="refresh"` is incorrectly being replaced with `<span class="keyword">http</span>-equiv="refresh"`

How can I leverage the `Node` metadata to filter `style` and other such tags from the results? *If at all possible, I'd like to avoid using regex to filter*.

eg. with `HTMLElement` I can do the following:

```
if (element.children[i].tagName === "SCRIPT") {
  // skip scripts
  continue;
}

if (element.children[i].tagName === "STYLE") {
  // skip style
  continue;
}
```

---

Replaced the custom dom walker with TreeWalker interface, but it still returns some JS tags:

```
const walker = document.createTreeWalker(
  root,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
);

let child: Node = walker.nextNode();

while (child) {
  console.log(child.textContent)
  child = walker.nextNode();
};
```

You can see the JS by running the following on a google search results page:

```
const walker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
);

let child = walker.nextNode();

while (child) {
  console.log(child.textContent)
  child = walker.nextNode();
};
```

I can add a filter to the TreeWalker, but that goes back to my original question -- how would I do that?

Comment: hard to help without any code ...

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on putting something together now. I started with this repo: `https://github.com/sszczep/chrome-extension-webpack` so I'm going back through my commits and re-adding everything to see when google stopped working. I didn't know if there was a known issue that folks who build extensions would jump straight to

Comment: @wOxxOm I had the implementation in the linked section, but using the TreeWalker implementation is preferred (I didn't know it existed). I've updated my code to leverage it (will post above in a moment), but it's still returning JS

Comment: Indeed a script element has a text node, but replacing there is not a problem because its code already ran and won't re-run. You may want to skip it anyway e.g. for cosmetic purposes by adding a check for `child.parentElement.tagName === 'SCRIPT'`

Comment: It seems like this took my full circle. I still prefer using the TreeWalker, no reason to loop over child nodes myself, but ultimately I'm still filtering on SCRIPT & STYLE; which I had been doing in the HTMLElement tree before the last round of feedback directed me towards using Nodes.